# Store in a docker package a builded/cmake result of libraries and dependencies and then add it to an existing Heroku app?

Tags: docker, heroku, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, heroku-api

Our application is running on Heroku. It deals with a lot of assets stored on S3 and I'm trying to add the possibility to transform GLTFs into USDZs.

Long story short, to generate a USDZ you need to build some binaries from [PixarAnimationStudios/USD](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD).

As it takes 1h+ to initialize and you need a bunch of other libraries we created an EC2 instance on AWS and installed everything there. It's ok, but we would like to have it on Heroku.

We read about [Docker Builds with heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker-builds-heroku-yml) but I'm not sure if this is what we actually need. We would need to "build and install" all the dependencies in a "package" and then have it deployed in our main API. The goal would be to "add this command" to our main API and be able to call it from bash.

My question would be: Can we store in a docker package a builded/cmake result of libraries and dependencies and then add it to an existing Heroku app?